# What should we do about the [help] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

We seem to have a new problem tag that newbies are throwing on a high percentage of posts: **[help](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/help)**. It's decreasing the signal-to-noise ratio, and I find it annoying, but I'm not sure how to best handle it.

For now, I just remove it on any post I see it on. There's no clear and obvious synonym to merge into, as people are just applying it to any arbitrary post regardless of its content.

What should we do about the [help](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/help) tag? Should I just keep monitoring it manually?

Comment: I thought "help" was what all of the SE sites were about, so I'm curious as to why it even exists as a tag!

Comment: My thoughts exactly!

Comment: I don't know enough about how the individual SE sites work. Working on the assumption that `[help]` is an OOB SE tag, is SFSE required to keep all of the "stock" tags? If not, I would vote to delete/disable/hide it.

Comment: @Moonpie: It is not a default tag (either on regular Stack Exchange sites or on meta sites like this one). As mentioned in [my answer](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3182/103153), a tag like "help" would be considered a "meta tag" (in that it doesn't describe the content of the question, but rather some other aspect of the question), so it would not be an appropriate use of a tag. The community should probably make an effort to remove it from all the questions on which it appears – then, it will automatically be removed from the system.

Answer (score 3):

In general, a tag like [help](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/help) would probably be considered a ["meta tag"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/): a tag that does not describe the content of the question, but rather some other aspect of the question – such as the author's skill level, the author's motivation for asking it, or what "kind" of question it is (poll, how-to, etc.). We don't need a tag that's just used on all questions to signify "I need help".

If the [help](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/help) tag is being used in this way, the community should make an effort to burninate it (see [this FAQ on MSE about burninating tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239190/335251)), if there is consensus from the community to do so. Once it's removed from all questions, it will automatically be removed from the system.

If the tag is successfully burninated, but then a user later recreates the tag, then it may be worth [blocking the tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/295148/335251). In this case, it needs to be burninated again; then, the community should make a meta post requesting that the tag be blocked, as detailed in this MSE post: [How do we request to have a tag blocked?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239189/335251). If there is a community consensus that the tag should be blocked, then the site moderators can [escalate this request to the staff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348642/335251) by adding the [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) tag to the meta post.